# Pull facebook comments on website via api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have facebook comments plugin intergrated with my site. The site has several 1000 pages & these comments section is on each page. It is a pain to goto each page & take a look at the comments. Following the admin emails aren't productive either.

Is there a way to pull ALL fb comments (on my site) via facebook api in ONE shot through a script?  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [comments of a domain](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7858168/comments-of-a-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [registered your domain](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/#claiming_a_domain) you should be able to use the [Comment moderation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) to see all the comments for the domain.

You may also be able to use FQL to do this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/